# Getting "no such session error" while trying to run simultaneously multiple Laravel Dusk tests

Tags: php, laravel, webdriver, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel Dusk to test an application and I'm would like to run several instances of tests at the same time.
I have 2 Laravel projects, each containing tests that are intended to a certain version of the application, which requires separates Chrome instances (the used ChromeDriver version is 2.28)

To do so, I run the `php artisan dusk` command in each project folder but I'm getting the following error after some time, making both Chrome instances crash :

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchDriverException: no such session
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
```

Is there a way to run these tests simultaneously in separate Chrome instances?

Comment: It seems like this is an issue others are having too, and it has been reported on their github. Try adding "sleep(1)" in your code to see if that helps your problem. Check the Issue on Github for clarification: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/105

Comment: I already tried but it unfortunately only solved the case when launching only a single test, not several at the same time.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided by Doomeyes? Note that for it to work for multiple tests you need to have each test in a separate file, like explained by him further down. https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/105#issuecomment-296411919

Comment: Adding the session()->flush() unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you were to post some of the code you are getting, to make sure that there isn't anything iffy about it.

Comment: I restart vagrant by running "vagrant reload --provision" and it's work for me.